LTSpice UniversalOpamp2 Rail to Rail Output
I am simulating this circuit in LTSpice:

What I expect to happen is as follows. U2 (UniversalOpamp2, default settings) should increase its output voltage until Vout matches Vref. Now, because Vref is equal to VCC, that's never going to happen. Therefore the output voltage of U2 should be equal to its supply voltage, VCC.
U2 is configured as shown here (default settings):

However, it outputs only 5.62V, not 6V. Why is that?

Maybe, the Ilimit is affecting the output already (in some way)?

Yeah, you need 30mA to drop 6V across 200ohms at the output, but I'm not sure if that's the whole reason for the 5.62V output voltage.

Hmmm...there is a switch internal to the opamp output that has an Ron of 10ohms and can get higher based on how close you are to ilimit.  That explains your exact situation.  However, if you insert a voltage follower using UniversalOpAmp2 in between your comparator and load, this internal resistance should be reduced by the negative feedback proportional to Avol...but that's not happening in my experiments.  I don't know if this is a mistake or intentional in the design of the model.  For a workaround you can use UniversalOpAmp1 as a voltage follower after your comparator.

I forgot that the internal output resistance is reduced by Avol only if you're operating within the linear region of the opamp.  If you are in saturation, then Avol no longer reduces the output resistance.

Whoops. I misunderstood your circuit and didn’t see the feedback the way it was drawn so I mistakenly called it a comparator. It’s irrelevant to the problem, though, but I still corrected this when writing my answer.

You have two things going on here.  The first one is hinted at by tobalt in the comments.  The Ilimit parameter is set to 25m which is very close to what the opamp is trying to drive.  This current limiting will affect the output voltage even if close to the limit, since it uses a hyperbolic tangent function to implement the limiting gradually instead of abruptly.

The second thing is the more prevalent factor.  There is a series resistance of 10Ω internal to the opamp output.  It is part of the Level 2 voltage-controlled switch which you can find defined in UniversalOpAmp2.lib:
.model Q SW(Ron=10 Roff=10Meg Vt=0 Vh=-.1 Vser={Rail} ilimit={Ilimit} noiseless level=2 epsilon={Rail/10})

The Ron=10 is the resistance I'm talking about. Normally, the negative feedback from Vout to the inverting input would reduce this resistance (along with your 50Ω resistor in series) by a factor of Avol.  However, this only works when the opamp is in its linear range of operation.  You're instead operating this opamp in saturation, which eliminates the effect of Avol and you're left with the following equivalent circuit for the output.

This issue is a little bit of a problem with how UniversalOpAmp2 was designed.  They should've made the output resistance a parameter you can set and only defaulted it to 10Ω instead of locking it at 10Ω.  I tried designing my own version of UniversalOpAmp2 a few years back, so I could get similar functionality in other simulators like ngspice.  It still needs work, like slew rate support and more consistent rail saturation points, but it's an example showing how Rout should be a settable parameter for a "universal" opamp model.
